# Oracle Change Web Interface URL

Tags: oracle, url-rewriting, oracle11g, virtual-hosts

In Oracle, is there a way to change the web interface URL? Usually, it is `localhost:8080`, but I don't like how that looks or the fact that I have to specify the port number.

I know I can use virtual hosts from Apache, node.js, nginx or some other server, then change my HOSTS file, but is there a way to change it specifically from the Oracle program?

I have 11g Express, but I will take answers from any version, as I will likely use others in the future.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but what web interface url?  Do you mean the pages for the Enterprise Manager (or something like it for the free version)? Ahh, I see it.  A smaller manager.

Comment: Does this help?  https://community.oracle.com/message/11226227